# Visual studio quick actions no longer work in Unreal 5.3 project

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine5

When defining a function in visual studio 2022 community edition, quick actions no longer seem available. The function no longer gets a line under the name, if you right click the function there is the option to do quick actions, however when you select it, it says none are available. So I can't quick define functions or anything like that.

I've done the following:

Deleted the binaries/intermediate/.vc/.vsconfig/sln files and rebuilt. No luck.
I've reset all settings in visual studio, no change
I've updated to the latest version of visual studio, no change
I'm currently repairing visual studio, but I'm not terribly hopeful. Update: Repair has finished and on restarting my machine and restarting visual studio I get an 'intellicodecpppackage failed to load' error. This time if I click quick actions it gives me some options, however trying to create the definition results in 'failed to return new code element' error.

Closed visual studio, deleted .vs and regenerated the solution. Opened it back up and now quick actions are gone again.

any ideas what's gone wrong here and how I can get this functionality back?

Edit: further digging, if I go into options c/c++->advanced and find the intellisense it says 'disable intellisense->true' but also the entire section is greyed out. There is no way to set that to false, and the other section for intellisense where it says 'enabled 64 bit intellisense' is also entirely greyed out.

Edit: Much closer to a solution

in advanced the browsing/navigation->disable database was set true for some reason. Setting this false opened up the rest of the options.

I also set recreate database to true. However on restart I still can't create the definition as it hangs on progress box for creating the definition.

Edit: Installed .Net SDK, tried again, this time it took about 25 seconds but it actually created the definition. The second definition created instantly. May be fixed.

Comment: Visual Studio tends to collapse under the UE5 project. There are paid plugins available like [Visual Assist](https://www.wholetomato.com/visual-assist-ue4-unreal-engine) and [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) that can deal with the problems. Other people use [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) and are happy with it. Unfortunately, I don't know any other solution except just buffing the tool with a plugin or switching alltogether. My team uses VA for a few years now and are happy with it, but it comes with a price tag attached.